# Select only one value from a column for each value in another column, together with corresponding other columns value

Tags: sql, sql-server

It seems to be a very simple problem but I couldn't solve it, imagine I have following table:

```
ID  MessageId   ReceiverId
----------------------------
1   1           1
2   1           2
3   2           3
4   3           1
5   3           2
```

I want to have a result which has unique values in it's `MessageId` column, meaning only one row which it's `MessageId` is 1, no matter which one.
something like this:

```
ID  MessageId   ReceiverId
----------------------------
1   1           1
3   2           3
4   3           1
```

I'm not going to use `GROUP BY` if it's supposed to return only one column since  I need all columns.

Comment: since when does GROUP BY only return one column? It does require you to use an aggregate function with it, though. In your example above, how should the code decide which of the rows with MessageIds 1 and 3 to return? What's the basis on which you chose the row you did for your output? It appears to be arbitrary, but perhaps you have a reason which is implementable?

Comment: In that case it returns all rows with no records filtering, meaning it contains duplicated `MessageId` values, I already tried it.

Comment: Please show what you tried, precisely. And please answer my question above, as well. Thankyou

Comment: Probably use Row_Number() Over (Partition by MessageID Order by ReceiverID) as RN  and then wrap it all in Where RN = 1

Comment: I didn't want to make it complicated by stating the reason, this table has more columns which I didn't mention in my question, and it's going to be joint in much more tables, but If you ask about the basis idea I can say that whenever you send a message to a group in a messenger like Telegram it's not important which receiver reads it, the first reader places that message in `seen` state.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need *correlated* subquery :

```
select m.*
from msg m
where id = (select top (1) id
            from msg m1 
            where m1.messageid = m.messageid
            order by m1.ReceiverId 
           );
```

Comment: It works like a charm but would you tell me if it's an expensive one? Performance I mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, messageId, receiverId
from
(
    select *,
           row_number() over(partition by messageId order by id) rnum
    from @t
) x
where x.rnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get best performance one needs to make use of CTE. Lets First create the table using Script:

```
 CREATE TABLE MyMessages(ID INT PRIMARY KEY ,  MessageId INT,   ReceiverId INT )
 GO 

INSERT INTO MyMessages values(1 ,  1 ,  1)
INSERT INTO MyMessages values(2 ,  1 ,  2)
INSERT INTO MyMessages values(3 ,  2 ,  3)
INSERT INTO MyMessages values(4 ,  3 ,  1)
INSERT INTO MyMessages values(5 ,  3 ,  2)
```

I think this query works fine for you.

```
;WITH UniqueMessages AS (SELECT MIN(ID) AS FirstID FROM MyMessages AS MM GROUP BY MM.MessageId)

SELECT  MM.ID, MM.MessageId, MM.ReceiverId 
FROM UniqueMessages AS UM 
INNER JOIN MyMessages AS MM ON MM.ID = UM.FirstID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CTE` with `RANK`

```
CREATE TABLE #test(ID INT, MessageId INT,  ReceiverId INT)
INSERT INTO #test VALUES
(1,1,1),
(2,1,2),
(3,2,3),
(4,3,1),
(5,3,2)

WITH val AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY MessageId ORDER BY ID) rnk
    FROM #test
    )
SELECT ID, MessageId, ReceiverId 
FROM val WHERE rnk = 1
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ID  MessageId   ReceiverId
1   1           1
3   2           3
4   3           1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM #myTable
WHERE ID IN
      (
          SELECT MIN(ID) FROM #myTable GROUP BY MessageId
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a row can only appear twice, I would recommend:

```
select m.*
from msgs m
where MessageId < ReceiverId
union all
select m.*
from msgs m
where MessageId > ReceiverId and
      not exists (select 1
                  from msgs m2
                  where m2.MessageId = m.ReceiverId and
                        m2.ReceiverId = m.MessageId
                 );
```

If you do have more than two rows possible, then you can use this solution which requires no subqueries:

```
select top (1) with ties m.*
from msgs m
order by row_number() over (order by case when MessageId < ReceiverId then MessageId 
                                           else ReceiverId
                                      end
                           );
```